# How to pass pageIndex in mat-paginator to API in Angular 9

Tags: angular

.html file

```
<mat-paginator [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25]"></mat-paginator>
```

.ts file

```
listCustomer() {
   
    this.customerservice
      .getCustomer(this.pageSize, this.paginator.pageIndex + 1)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.list = res["success"].data;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.list);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
       
    });
}
```

[image]
my error is:

```
core.js:4061 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageIndex' of undefined
```

How can i fix this issue?

This is example on [stackblatz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-9dfdmt)

Answer (score 0):

```
 .getCustomer(this.pageSize, this.paginator.pageIndex + 1)
```

seems like this.paginator is null

u have to use [viewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) to get reference to paginator

```
// component
    @ViewChild('paginatorComp') paginator: MatPaginator;

// html
<mat-paginator #paginatorComp [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25]"> </mat-paginator>
```

Comment: i have done the same.. but shows same error. Should i define some thing else                      
can explain method to pass pageSize and pageIndex on getCustomer request to get data baased on pageIndex

Comment: please create demo on https://stackblitz.com/ and share link

Comment: Iam using angular 9 . is there any in change in Angular 9 for paginator property

Comment: fork it and then create ur example in it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-9dfdmt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-9dfdmt

Comment: it has other errors please AppservicetsService service

Comment: that is because  need to pass tocken along with request to get data...

Comment: just remove AppservicetsService service.
focus on one issue/time

Comment: please check ans again

Answer (score 0):

If you use the viewChild probably need implement the AfterViewInit cycle hook and use the paginator into this hook. Because into the OnInit you can't access yet to this data.